# Scipy-interp2d returned function sorts input argument automatically and undesirably

Tags: python, scipy

Following the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
y = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(xx+yy)
f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind='cubic')
```

I proceed to evaluate f:

```
xnew = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 1e-2)
f(xnew, 0)
```

Output:

```
array([ 0.95603946,  0.9589498 ,  0.96176018, ..., -0.96443103,
   -0.96171273, -0.96171273])
```

Reversing the argument gives the same result! I was expecting to get the reversed one:

```
xnewrev=np.array(list(reversed(np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 1e-2))))
f(xnewrev, 0)
```

Output:

```
array([ 0.95603946,  0.9589498 ,  0.96176018, ..., -0.96443103,
   -0.96171273, -0.96171273])
```

Expected:

```
array([-0.96171273, -0.96171273, -0.96443103, ...,  0.96176018,
    0.9589498 ,  0.95603946])
```

I get the same result also after shuffling `xnew`. It seems the interpolated function `f` sorts `xnew` before evaluation. How can I make `f` return values in the same order as given in the input list?

Somehow this is not an issue with interp1d.

I'm using Jupyter notebook, Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

Your `f` callable takes an `assume_sorted` parameter:

```
assume_sorted : bool, optional
    If False, values of `x` and `y` can be in any order and they are
    sorted first.
    If True, `x` and `y` have to be arrays of monotonically
    increasing values.
```

So, yes, the inputs are sorted internally if you haven't sorted them before hand.  I don't see a way of getting the sorted coordinates back.

The `x`,`y` inputs to `interp2d` are also sorted before use.  Apparently the interpolation calculations require sorted arrays.

You can recover a pre-sort order with a double `argsort` index

Make an array and shuffle it:

```
In [415]: xnew = np.arange(-10,11,2)
In [416]: xnew
Out[416]: array([-10,  -8,  -6,  -4,  -2,   0,   2,   4,   6,   8,  10])
In [417]: np.random.shuffle(xnew)
In [418]: xnew
Out[418]: array([  0,   2,   6,  -2,  10,  -4,   8,  -8, -10,  -6,   4])
```

Get the recovery index:

```
In [419]: idx = np.argsort(np.argsort(xnew))
In [420]: idx
Out[420]: array([ 5,  6,  8,  4, 10,  3,  9,  1,  0,  2,  7], dtype=int32)
```

test it:

```
In [421]: np.sort(xnew)[idx]
Out[421]: array([  0,   2,   6,  -2,  10,  -4,   8,  -8, -10,  -6,   4])
```

Comment: Doesn't sorting x and y defeat the purpose of interpolating at specific new x,y coordinates?  For example, if I want to interpolate at points (x=0, y=3) and (x=2, y=1) then the x-coordinates are x = (0, 2) and the y-coordinates are y = (3, 1). After sorting, these become x = (0, 2) and y = (1, 3) which interpolates the points (x=0, y=1) and (x=2, y=2) neither of which is one of the requested coordinates for interpolation.

Comment: Also, I'm fairly sure that depending on the version of scipy used, the "assume_sorted" parameter may not exist.

Comment: @BrianD, I answered this in 2017, so unless you are using a real old version, `assume_sorted` exists.  While the input points may be scattered, the interpolation returns a "2-D array with shape (len(y), len(x))", a grid.  With `[0,2]` and `[1,3]` you get 4 points - the 2 you want and 2 bonus points.

Comment: I'm stuck using 0.12.1 which is from 2013

Comment: Before this patch 7 years ago it expected sorted arrays. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/c0845ef24b7fbcfa7419ec87e12321cacb865c39  @BrianD

Answer (score 0):

Based on [hpaulj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44941822/1862861), you could define a new class that returns the unsorted array, e.g.,

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import numpy as np

class unsorted_interp2d(interp2d):
    def __call__(self, x, y, dx=0, dy=0):
        unsorted_idxs = np.argsort(np.argsort(x))
        return interp2d.__call__(self, x, y, dx=dx, dy=dy)[unsorted_idxs]
```

And then, in your example, you would have:

```
x = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
y = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(xx+yy)
f = unsorted_interp2d(x, y, z, kind='cubic')

xnewrev=np.array(list(reversed(np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 1e-2))))
f(xnewrev, 0)

# the expected output!
array([-0.96171273, -0.96171273, -0.96443103, ...,  0.96176018,
        0.9589498 ,  0.95603946])
```