# Python 2d interpolation for masked or unordered input data

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, masked-array

The data that I have is the frequency *(`f`)* and theta *(`th`) *which are coordinates that correspond to a 2d object beam *(`b`)*. i.e: `(f_i, th_i) == b_ii`.

I set up the 2d interpolation using `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`. Works well, until I use new input data in descending order or with masked arrays *(the mask values become `0`)* which re-orders the data such that zero values are first.

If I re-apply the mask it will appear in the incorrect place due to the ordering of the data. Does anyone have a simple workaround?

Note:
New input values are within the bounds of the original grid setup.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from [Scipy-interp2d returned function sorts input argument automatically and undesirably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941271/scipy-interp2d-returned-function-sorts-input-argument-automatically-and-undesira/53630086#53630086)

Based on the submitted at link above

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import numpy as np

class unsorted_interp2d(interp2d):
    def __call__(self, x, y, dx=0, dy=0):
        unsorted_idxs = np.argsort(np.argsort(x))
        return interp2d.__call__(self, x, y, dx=dx, dy=dy)[:,unsorted_idxs]
```

Just changed `[unsorted_idxs]` to `[:,unsorted_idxs]` to work for all x values in the 2d object